# arithmetic between limits

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

I need find $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}( x^3-x^2)=L$.
In this case, I ended up with infinity minus infinity.
But I do know $x^3$ is always greater than $x^2$ for $x\ge1$ and the difference
between them is growing... Can I say $L$ is infinity? Is there a formal way to prove or show this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid arguments such as "this infinity is greater than this one..."; you have the right idea (especially since you note the difference between them is growing), but  it's a bit vague and can sometimes mislead you.

To find the limit rigorously, use the following
hint: Write $x^3-x^2 =x^3(1-{1\over x})$.

Comment: what if the original expression I have is lim n!-2^n?

Comment: @cssl That would be harder. What I have above works nicely for any polynomial, though.  For $n!-2^n$, you might write$$n!-2^n=2^n\Bigl(\underbrace{{n\over2}\cdot{n-1\over 2}\cdot{n-2\over 2}\cdots{3\over2}\cdot{2\over2}\cdot{1\over 2}}_{\ge2}-1\Bigr)$$ for $n\ge 5$.